# "Unable to create/update fields: VersionData" error when updating a ContentNote from Apex

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, contentnote

I have some Apex code that inserts a `ContentNote` and the corresponding `ContentDocumentLink`. This works fine and the data can be viewed through the normal Salesforce UI.

But some further code that updates the content (in a separate transaction) fails with this DmlException:

> Unable to create/update fields: VersionData. Please check the security
>   settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your
>   profile or permission set.

Now `VersionData` is a field in the underlying [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) object and the Content objects are not surfaced (as far as I can see) in profiles. So I presume this is being caused by something else.

I'm inserting the `ContentDocumentLink` with these settings:

```
    cdl.put('ShareType', 'I');
    cdl.put('Visibility', 'AllUsers');
```

Any idea how to stop this error from happening?

Comment: It occurs to me that this might be a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) problem as `ContentNote` acts as a facade over `ContentDocument`/`ContentDocumentVersion`. Not sure of the solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having found this [ConvertNotesToContentNotesService](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-notes-to-chatter-notes/blob/master/src/classes/ConvertNotesToContentNotesService.cls) class - thanks for posting that code [Doug Ayers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/987/doug-ayers) - I realised that there is a `Blob` field on the `ContentVersion` object after all that I had overlooked because it is called "VersionData" not "Content"...

So instead of updating `ContentNote`, I am now successfully inserting a `ContentVersion` object created like this:

```
private static SObject createContentVersion(SObject cn) {

    SObject cnv = ContentNotes.versionType.newSObject();

    cnv.put('ContentDocumentId', cn.Id);
    cnv.put('Title', cn.get('Title'));
    cnv.put('VersionData', cn.get('Content'));

    // This chosen based on inspection of a note created through standard UI
    cnv.put('PathOnClient', cn.get('Title') + '.snote');

    return cnv;
}
```